# Trouble passing in lambda to apply for pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I'm trying to apply a function to all rows of a pandas DataFrame (actually just one column in that DataFrame)

I'm sure this is a syntax error but I'm know sure what I'm doing wrong

```py
df['col'].apply(lambda x, y:(x - y).total_seconds(), args=[d1], axis=1)
```

The `col` column contains a bunch a `datetime.datetime` objects and `d1` is the earliest of them. I'm trying to get a column of the total number of seconds for each of the rows.

I keep getting the following error

```
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```

I don't understand why `axis` is getting passed to my `lambda` function

I've also tried doing

```py
def diff_dates(d1, d2):
    return (d1-d2).total_seconds()

df['col'].apply(diff_dates, args=[d1], axis=1)
```

And I get the same error.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Note **there is no `axis` param for a [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) call**, as distinct to a [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) call.

> Series.apply(func, convert_dtype=True, args=(), **kwds)

```
func : function
convert_dtype : boolean, default True
Try to find better dtype for elementwise function results. If False, leave as dtype=object
args : tuple
Positional arguments to pass to function in addition to the value
```

There is one for a [df](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) but it's unclear how you're expecting this to work when you're calling it on a series but you're expecting it to work on a row?

Answer (score 1):

A single column is (usually) a pandas Series, and as [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29155455/19123103) mentioned, `DataFrame.apply` has `axis` argument but `Series.apply` hasn't, so `apply` on `axis=1` wouldn't work on columns.

The following works:

```py
df['col'].apply(lambda x, y: (x - y).total_seconds(), args=(d1,))
```

For applying a function for each element in a row, `map` can also be used:

```py
df['col'].map(lambda x: (x - d1).total_seconds())
```

As `apply` is just a syntactic sugar for a Python loop, a list comprehension may be more efficient than both of them because it doesn't have the pandas overhead:

```py
[(x - d1).total_seconds() for x in df['col'].tolist()]
```

For a single column DataFrame, `axis=1` may be passed:

```py
df[['col']].apply(lambda x, y: (x - y).dt.total_seconds(), args=[d1], axis=1)
```

##### PSA: Avoid `apply` if you can

`apply` is not even needed *most of the time*. For the case in the OP (and most other cases), a vectorized operation exists (just subtract `d1` from the column - the value is broadcast to match the column) and is much faster than `apply` anyway:

```py
(df['col'] - d1).dt.total_seconds()
```

##### Timings

The vectorized subtraction is about 150 times faster than `apply` on a column and over 7000 times faster than `apply` on a single column DataFrame for a frame with 10k rows. As `apply` is a loop, this gap gets bigger as the number of rows increase.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': pd.date_range('2000', '2023', 10_000)})
d1 = df['col'].min()

%timeit df['col'].apply(lambda x, y: (x - y).total_seconds(), args=[d1])
# 124 ms ± 7.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit df['col'].map(lambda x: (x - d1).total_seconds())
# 127 ms ± 16.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit [(x - d1).total_seconds() for x in df['col'].tolist()]
# 107 ms ± 4.14 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit (df['col'] - d1).dt.total_seconds()
# 851 µs ± 189 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit df[['col']].apply(lambda x, y: (x - y).dt.total_seconds(), args=[d1], axis=1)
# 6.07 s ± 419 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```